# How to translate "for the sake of"?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

Is "en aras de" the accepted translation of "for the sake of"?

Say you want to translate something like this:

> they are fighting *for the sake of* their freedom

Would this make sense?

> ellos luchan **en aras de** su libertad

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that would be acceptable.

"en aras de" means something like "in the interest of", "because of" - which is how "for the sake of" is defined as well.

Instead of "en aras de" you might use "por":

> ellos luchan **por** su libertad

Comment: Argentinian here - the translation is correct, but you don't say "en aras de". It's not a common expression to use at this latitudes. You may only hear that in a written speech or ad or something like that - a really pre-thought phrase, nothing _natural_.

Comment: It may depend on the context of the translation; if it's a "formal" or "literary" translation, *"en aras de"* or *"en pos de"* can work. If it's meant for verbal communication, "por" would be better (greetings from Mexico)

Comment: @mgarciaisaia Agreed. Never ever heard it spoken before.